# TimeZone exception from JPA, but this params are already added

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I have jpa +spring +mysql
my DataConfig is:

```
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"data"})
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"data.persistence"})
public class DataConfig {
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("111111");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManager.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    //Set properties hibernate
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use Repository to make entity, there is error message:

> 26-Sep-2018 19:38:16.627 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection] with root cause 
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The
>   server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (????)' is unrecognized or represents
>   more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC
>   driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more
>   specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)

Comment: check your db time zone. It seems there is conflict your mysql time zone what are you setting.

Comment: @Suresh mySql db time zone is RTZ 2 (???   , so do you mean this value?

Comment: which Mysql Driver ar e you using?

Comment: used 8 version of my sql. issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

fixed by SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';  execution on my base.